# How to print out all the links to files in "docs" directory in an unordered list?

Tags: php, html-lists, echo, href

Files are submitted by user, so I dont know how many of them will there be and what would be their name.

```
<?php
echo "<ul>";
$files = scandir('docs/');
foreach($files as $file) {
  echo "<li>$file[name]</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
# 
This is what I have now, but it shows "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in D:\xampp\htdocs\zwa\cvic3.php:57 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\zwa\cvic3.php on line 57 (echo "<li>$file[name]</li>";)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in second echo, look closer at quotes;

```php
$filename = $file['name'];
echo "<li>$filename</li>";
```